# Show that $p(1)=0 $ and $p(2)>0$

Tags: polynomials, continuity

Let $p$ be a real polynomial of the real variable $x$ of the form $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots a_1x-1$.Suppose that $p$ has no roots in the open unit disc and $p(-1)=0$.

> Show that $p(1)=0 $ and $p(2)>0$

I am unable to understand how to show this proof.Please help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product of all the roots of $p$ has absolute value $1$.  Since none of the roots has absolute value less than $1$, none of them can have absolute value greater than $1$ either.  Since the coefficients of $p$ are real, $p(0)=-1$ and $p(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, there must be a positive real root, which must therefore be $1$.  Finally, $p(2)$ cannot be negative (much less $0$) since otherwise there would be another real root greater than $1$.

Note, the assumption $p(-1)=0$ is irrelevant.